# Asp.net Core Dynamically inserting HTML elements in a specific position based on model values

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor

I have figured out a way to dynamically insert child elements into a specific parent div element based on the status property from the model. The problem with my version is that I am using 4 loops to achieve this. Is there a better way to achieve this? like 1 loop.

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            if (item.Status == OrderStatus.New)
            {
                <div class="order"></div>
            }
        }
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            if (item.Status == OrderStatus.Preparing)
            {
                <div class="order"></div>
            }
        }
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            if (item.Status == OrderStatus.Delivering)
            {
                <div class="order"></div>
            }
        }
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            if (item.Status == OrderStatus.Delivered)
            {
                <div class="order"></div>
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see that I am adding a bunch of div tags into one of the 4 columns based on the status. I am using a loop for each one to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Just take this loop outside of this elements and check if item has expected status. Is this what are you looking for?

```
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {  
        <div class="col-lg-3">
                if (item.Status == OrderStatus.New)
                {
                    <div class="order"></div>
                }
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
                if (item.Status == OrderStatus.Preparing)
                {
                    <div class="order"></div>
                }
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
                if (item.Status == OrderStatus.Delivering)
                {
                    <div class="order"></div>
                }
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
                if (item.Status == OrderStatus.Delivered)
                {
                    <div class="order"></div>
                }
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Edited version:

```
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {  
        if (item.Status == OrderStatus.New)
        {
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="order"></div>
            </div>
        }
        if (item.Status == OrderStatus.Preparing)
        {
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="order"></div>
            </div>
        }
        if (item.Status == OrderStatus.Delivering)
        {
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="order"></div> 
            </div>
         }
        if (item.Status == OrderStatus.Delivered)
        {
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="order"></div>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Would this not create 3 columns on each loop? This is the issue I was having.

Comment: So you can just take statements outside of divs. I edited my answer to show you idea.

Comment: This is still an issue. I want 4 fixed columns and that's it. I want those 4 columns to be populated with orders. Your edited way  will still not work as there can be like 20 orders and it will create 20 columns. I need 4 columns only.

Answer (score 0):

Add `break` to your consition like below:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.Status == OrderStatus.New)
        {
            <div class="order"></div>
            break;                
        }
    }
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.Status == OrderStatus.Preparing)
        {
            <div class="order"></div>
            break;
        }
    }
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.Status == OrderStatus.Delivering)
        {
            <div class="order"></div>
            break;
        }
    }
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.Status == OrderStatus.Delivered)
        {
            <div class="order"></div>
            break;
        }
    }
</div>
```